# When to create an EndPoint?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-endpoints

> What is the use case /scenario where should I create an EndPoint in
>   google app engine project ?

I know that I can send my data from my mobile client to App server(GAE) using one EndPoint and receive data from App Server(GAE) using the same or another EndPoint. But I am not able to understand when i should create/use another EndPoint for receiving data and not use the same EndPoint using which I sent the data.

> Is it advisable to have same EndPoint to be used for mobile client and
>   web client?

Any help will be appreciated!!
thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the use case /scenario where should I create an EndPoint in google app engine project?

Endpoints should be created on a class basis. So you use the same endpoint class for sending and receiving foo objects (but obviously you use different methods). It's just a REST api, so you'll want to create your basic CRUD methods. Generate an endpoint in Eclipse and you'll see what the intended/generic use cases are.

> Is it advisable to have same EndPoint to be used for mobile client and web client?

Yes, that's the point of a REST api; it doesn't matter what the client is. From the [overview page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/):
[image]